# How often can we use garbarge collection in C#

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, memory-usage

I would like to use garbage collection several times after calling some external dlls. And I wonder how often can I do this, without causing problems to my application.

I'm using the following codes

```
// Force garbage collection.
GC.Collect();

// Wait for all finalizers to complete before continuing.
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Can someone advise me on this, and where are the suitable places that I can  place the above codes. I use a lot of arrays and variables and memory in my software

Comment: Explicitly forcing GC is almost always wrong and will likely slow your application down. Unless you actually know more about the memory usage patterns of your application than the people who implemented the garbage collector, don't do this. Your question sounds like you don't have a very accurate mental model of C# and the Common Language Runtime. And that is OK – but right now you'll likely benefit more from focusing on higher-level programming and design skills than low-level runtime tuning.

Comment: You can do this most probably as often as you like (it will obviously slow your application down, and we cannot tell you how often you can call the GC until the performance drops so much it gets a problem for your application, that is something you have to measure by yourself). But better ask if you *should* call the GC by yourself at all, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233596/best-practice-for-forcing-garbage-collection-in-c-sharp

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question well without a decent explication of WHY you want to do this. Otherwise all you get from us are warnings about what doing this foolishly will cost you.

Comment: You decided to use a garbage collected language and now you seem to regret it. Why?

Comment: @amon Uhh... *of course* you "actually know more about the memory usage patterns of your application than the people who implemented the garbage collector".  They don't know anything about your application; they only know generalities.  For example, they don't know when you just finished loading a large amount of data, which is likely to generate a bunch of intermediate garbage along the way.  The application developer does.  This is a very good time to explicitly call the GC, because the user is expecting it to take a bit of noticeable time anyway and then you don't pause later on.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Someone who doesn't know *anything* about resource allocation *at all*, because they have only used languages that have an abstraction layer that hides it from them absolutely might not know more than "we profiled a whole variety of program types to come up with these heuristics, and believe the result to be widely applicable"

Answer (score 9):

In general, asking the garbage collector to collect is more of a recommendation than an actual order.

You should not do this at all. The garbage collector will properly respond to memory pressure. And like every optimization, measure first. Once you *actually* have GC slowness, then worry about fixing it.

Comment: And more often than not, switching to a different GC algorithm and/or implementation is both less work and provides better gains than manual micro-optimizing. The only problem in the .NET space is that the choice of GCs is rather limited (compared to e.g. Java, Smalltalk, or Lisp).

Comment: Also depending on what's in those external DLLs calling the GC may do absolutely nothing useful.

Comment: Sorry, but this is simply wrong.  The garbage collector will properly respond to memory pressure, but that's nowhere near the optimal situation, because that's the only thing it knows about.  It doesn't understand *appropriateness,* (ie. we don't want GC pauses while the system should be responsive,) nor does it understand "we just did something unusual for our program that's likely to have generated a bunch of garbage."  The developer is the only one who understands such things.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: GC can't achieve **optimal** performance, but for probably the vast majority of applications, GC can and does achieve **good enough** performance, and unless the OP is writing control software for the Death Star's laser, **good enough** is all you need, and is disingenuous to say the more general case, is "simply wrong".

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to use garbage collection several times after calling some external dlls.

Why do you feel the need to do this?

> ... I wonder how often can I do this, without causing problems to my application.

I would say: None.

Garbage Collection clumps all objects together into three "Generations": Generation 0 is aggressively purged of "dead" objects, "Generation 1" less aggressively and "Generation 2" if and when the run-time ever gets around to bothering. 
After *each* GC run, objects are promoted "up" from one generation to the next so, by running it manually, you're forcing objects "up" into the *less-well managed* Generations, which basically *bloats* your application memory instead of freeing it.

Comment: And how is this any different from what happens when the GC runs automatically?

Comment: @MasonWheeler Think about the pathological example where someone forces a collection after every single object allocation. The idea that an object that survives a collection is long-lived assumes that meaningful work is getting done between collections.

Comment: @doval Sure, but if you bring up pathological cases you can make *anything* look ridiculous, so that's not a particularly persuasive example.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the GC manually when you're in a situation where you know that you've generated a lot of garbage, but the garbage collector doesn't.

The garbage collector isn't all that smart.  It doesn't know anything at all about how your program works; all it knows is that when there's memory pressure it needs to collect in order to relieve it.  In order to satisfy this constraint, a generational garbage collector has to use the stupidest possible algorithm: *let as much garbage build up as possible before collecting.*

You can do better than that, because you know how your program works.  You don't want GC pauses when the program is supposed to be responsive, and you don't want big memory bloats where it's holding on to stuff it doesn't need anymore.  So a good rule of thumb is to manually invoke the GC at points where the system is likely to generate a lot of garbage *and* the user doesn't expect it to be responsive anyway, such as at the end of a data loading cycle.  (ie. the user says `Open...` in the menu.)  The garbage collector doesn't know that this is a good time for it to run, but you do.

Comment: I'd recommend caveat'ing this to "and you profiled without manually invoking GC collections and found it unperformant". You have to measure to know that there is any improvement. Some programs never need to collect, so manually calling it is a pessimisation

Comment: "Some programs never need to collect" is simply not true on a modern multitasking system, which is essentially everywhere where managed code runs.  You're not the only one using that RAM, which is *another* thing the GC doesn't know about.  Unless you're writing code strictly for personal/internal use, your program should not walk in like it owns the place because it is a guest in someone else's home, and needs to behave accordingly.